# How to create a well-typed function that returns two different types?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I'm highly interested in compiling [Formality-Core](https://github.com/moonad/Formality-Core) modules to Haskell libraries. While I could use `unsafeCoerce` everywhere, it would be more interesting if I could preserve the type information, allowing compiled modules to be published on Cabal and used by other Haskell projects. The problem is that dependent types allow programs that are forbidden by Haskell. For example, the function `foo` below:

```
foo: (b : Bool) -> If(b)(Nat)(Bool)
  (b)
  b<(b) If(b)(Nat)(Bool)>
  | zero;
  | false;
```

Returns a different type depending on the input. If the input is `false`, it returns the number `zero`. If the input is `true`, it returns the boolean `false`. It seems like a function like this can't be translated to Haskell. I believe that, on the last years, Haskell has made good progress towards dependent type, so, I wonder: **is there any way to write functions that return different types based on the input value?**

Comment: As much progress as has been made, the one core feature of dependent types - the ability for the compiler to "look into" the values at compile time - is still lacking. In order to express that in Haskell, you'd have to either pull the parameter `b: Bool` to the type level, so it's known at compile time, or the opposite - pull down the resulting type to the value level.

Comment: Is the `Either` monad what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd avoid `unsafeCoerce` unless no other option works. We have GADTs+singletons to mimic some dependent types. We also have `Dynamic` that performs runtime type checking, if a static approach can't work. Possibly other safe options exist.

Comment: @chi I find the singletons approach in the answers very interesting since it does allow some sort of dependency, but in retrospect I feel like it won't be powerful enough to represent arbitrary dependent functions. So I'm not very sure how to proceed. Perhaps the only viable alternative is to just compile everything to a HOAS DSL, but I guess we'll lose a lot of native performance by doing that...

Comment: @bug_spray No, it's not. `Either` only lets the *value* of the output depend on the input value, since `Left 0` and `Right False` are the same type, namely `Either Natural Bool`. This is about getting the *type* of the output to depend on the input value. (And even if it were, the fact that it's a monad isn't relevant. You shouldn't call things monads just because they have a `Monad` instance unless you're actually referring to or using the instance somehow.)

Answer (score 6):

The state of the art remains the singleton approach.

```
data SBool b where
  SFalse :: SBool 'False
  STrue :: SBool 'True

type family If (b :: Bool) (t1 :: k) (t2 :: k) :: k where
  If 'False x _ = x
  If 'True _ y = y

foo :: SBool b -> If b Natural Bool
foo SFalse = 0
foo STrue = False
```

Answer (score 6):

GADTs + TypeFamilies (optionally, + DataKinds) can do roughly this. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data GADTBool a where
    GADTFalse :: GADTBool False
    GADTTrue :: GADTBool True

type family If cond t f where
    If False t f = f
    If True  t f = t

foo :: GADTBool b -> If b Int Bool
foo GADTTrue = 0
foo GADTFalse = False
```

Of course, you'll probably actually want `foo :: GADTBool b -> If b (GADTInt 0) (GADTBool False)` if you plan to do this kind of thing pervasively. The search term you want for seeing more examples of this kind of hackery is "singleton types", often abbreviated just "singletons".

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe worth noting that, as a practical matter, the `singletons` library can be used to take care of most of the boilerplate.  So, you can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Formality where

import Numeric.Natural
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

foo :: SBool b -> If b Bool Natural
foo SFalse = 0
foo STrue = False
```

using almost exactly the syntax used by @dfeuer, up to the order of arguments to `If`.

The main disadvantage of the `singletons` library is that any serious type dependent programming is going to eventually require understanding how things are actually implemented internally, and the guts of the library are complicated and not very well documented.

You may find it helpful to start by hand-compiling some Formality using a from-scratch solution using your own singleton GADTs and type families (as in the other answers), and then try to convert it over to use `singletons`.